# how to retrieve textbox string form mainpage in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to UWP.

I have created an app with a MainPage and a UserControl.

I have a TextBox in that UserControl and I want to access its data from my Mainpage.

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Peter have a good answer but I think you also can use `FieldModifier`.

My UserControl is Averieli and my xaml is :

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Avalonia.Averieli"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Avalonia"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
       <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" x:FieldModifier="public"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can see that I add `x:FieldModifier="public"` in TextBox that can make it can be used in MainPage.

I use the UserControl in MainPage.

```
    <local:Averieli x:Name="Averieli"></local:Averieli>
```

I also can use the TextBox in the back code.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Averieli.TextBox.Text = "I can use it";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the user control, initialise a static global instance of the UserControl class

```
public UserControl()
{
    //Initialise control
}

public static UserControl UserControlInstance
{
    get
    {
        return m_UserControlInstance ?? new UserControl();
    }
}

private static UserControl m_UserControlInstance;
```

And then just access properties of UserControl via the instance

```
string x = UserControl.UserControlInstance.TextBox.Text;
```

This is called a singelton by the way, in case you wanted to look it up!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but when i try to access textbox from my mainpage with UserControl.UserControlInstance.textbox i can not find textbox property. But in my userControl i have a textbox with that x:name.